# Retrieve enhanced List views for Flows via metadata API?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, mdapideploy

Currently, whenever we retrieve an object via sfdx, whether custom, standard or cmtd, it will retrieve the list views too.

However, I cannot seem to find the correct metadata folder or xml which contains the Flow list views.

Has anyone tried to do this and retrieved successfully?

Many thanks.